# Identify live or neutral in 2-way switch

Tags: switches, test

I have a 2-way switch connecting to a light and it works properly. When opening it up, it has 3 inputs with the same wire color. I don't know the setup and I wish to know if there is a neutral in one of them and how were they wired.

I did a simple test for "live" among the 3 wires, these are the result.
by using a simple "testing screw driver" and testing on the switch

1. When the light is off (case 1), wire 1 tested to have "live" signal, wire 2 and 3 do not have.
2. When the light is off (case 2), wire 3 tested to have "live" signal, wire 1 and 2 do not have.
3. When the light is on (both case), 3 of them have "live" signal.

Given the wiring diagram from [Electronics Hub - How a 2 Way Switch Wiring Works?](https://www.electronicshub.org/2-way-switch-wiring/), it doesn't make sense to me.

[image]

How can it be and what is the setup?
thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121073/discussion-on-question-by-daydayhappy-identify-live-or-neutral-in-2-way-switch).

Answer (score 1):

A SPDT is like an XOR logic gate. The sector can only exclusively selector 1 or the other which in logic inverts the output (on/off).

For electricians, the 3 wires is related to the switch name "3-way"  , for Engineers we simply them SPDT. And for students of logic an "XOR switch"...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvL9sV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Second and third version senseless, because if supply and load in different junction boxes, four wire need between switches. Wasting of materials.

Comment: second case depicts what the OP is describing and satisfies the requirement of working "correctly"

Comment: Good point @user263983 .. changes made

Comment: Third schematic is wrong because neutral wire can not be switched or disconnected. In second connection can be made with 3 wires only if feed and load wires come into one connection box. Connection for 3-way switches is pretty standard.

Comment: 3rd is hard wired to N not switched (?). Explain contradiction on 2. It is what you said.  @user263983. Or make changes you think works better

Comment: 3rd schematic neutral switched on way to load. Electrical wires in house run in conduit or cable. Conduit and cable run between boxes, fixture placed in box, connection made inside box only. 3-way switches placed in different boxes toq have comfortable access.  Power feed and cable to load may be in same box or in different. 3 wire cable run between boxes. Then feed and load connected in different boxes,3 wire is not enough. May point is only first schematic is proper.

Comment: Second and third is the same. Instead third read fourth.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard staircase light schematic employing two SPDT switches, one located at the foot of  the stairs and the other at the head, to facilitate 'switching on' or 'switching off' of the light from either location.

The neutral is connected to one terminal of the light, with the other terminal being connected to or disconnected from the line by either of the switches.